# Jquery Mobile swipe change aspx page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i have an aspx. page with a swipe event in it! when the event fires it should change to another aspx page! It works fine but the new aspx page comes up on the same aspx page where the event was fired! Now i have both contents on one side...but i want only the content from the new aspx page to be shown...

Here´s my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<div data-role="page" id="Default">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="swipeRight">
            <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Images/TestSeite.png" runat="server" />
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#swipeLeft").live('swipeleft', function (event, ui) {
            $.mobile.changePage("/Default.aspx", "slide");
        });

        $("#swipeRight").live('swiperight', function () {
            $.mobile.changePage("/Madrid.aspx", "slide");
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

swipe and swipeleft will both be fired if the user swipes left, as swipe accounts for all four directions.

You should most likely be using swipeleft and swiperight.

Comment: Do you have an example somewhere, have you tried loading those page not via AJAX eg $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;

Comment: still doesnt work...And in my swiperight div a have a big LOADING...i dont know where that come from....